# strpos() not working as expected

Tags: php

I'm checking some html for a string and the result I'm getting is not as expected

```
$html = "<body><a href="http://domain32a.com">Link</a></body>";

if(strpos($html, "href=\"http://domain.com") === FALSE)
    echo "Not Found";
else
    echo "Found";
```

It always return "Found" even though it's **not actually found (I don't want it found)** in this example?

Should I be using a different function?

Comment: Does your `$html` variable really look like that? You need to either escape the quotes (i.e., `$html = "<body><a href=\"http://domain32a.com\">Link</a></body>";`) or encapsulate your string in single quotes instead (i.e., `$html = '<body><a href="http://domain32a.com">Link</a></body>';`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string http://domain32a.com isn't same as http://domain.com. You also have some syntax errors, try:

```
$html = "<body><a href=\"http://domain32a.com\">Link</a></body>";
if(strpos($html, "href=\"http://domain32a.com") === FALSE)
    echo "Not Found";
else
    echo "Found";
```

Comment: I know it isn't the same, it shouldn't be found but it always shows found

Comment: when i changed it to strpos($html, "href=\"http://domain.com") - it prints "Not found".

Answer (score 0):

Change Your code to this

```
<?php
   $html = "<body><a href='http://domain32a.com'>Link</a></body>";
   if(strpos($html, "href=\"http://domain.com") === FALSE){
   echo "Not Found";
   } else {
   echo "Found";
   }
?>
```